# How to fetch the Machine Name ,Protocol and Port number from URL format using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

From the URL format , how to fetch the Protocol, Machine Name and Port Number using powershell.

This page [fetch protocol and port number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ew9az0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using C#. But I also want to fecth the machine name and need to use powershell.

Comment: You could just construct a [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and access the appropriate properties (noting, of course, that you can get the `Authority` which is the domain name or IP address. There's no way to know from a URI what the *actual* name of the machine is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use :

```
$a = [System.Uri]"http://www.contoso.com:8080/letters/readme.html"
```

Then :

```
$a | fl *

AbsolutePath   : /letters/readme.html
AbsoluteUri    : http://www.contoso.com:8080/letters/readme.html
LocalPath      : /letters/readme.html
Authority      : www.contoso.com:8080
HostNameType   : Dns
IsDefaultPort  : False
IsFile         : False
IsLoopback     : False
PathAndQuery   : /letters/readme.html
Segments       : {/, letters/, readme.html}
IsUnc          : False
Host           : www.contoso.com
Port           : 8080
Query          : 
Fragment       : 
Scheme         : http
OriginalString : http://www.contoso.com:8080/letters/readme.html
DnsSafeHost    : www.contoso.com
IsAbsoluteUri  : True
UserEscaped    : Fa
```

So for the protocol `Http` is given by :

```
$a.Scheme
```